# ASP.NET MVC - How to add a Class to Html.EditorFor when classes already exist due to unobtrusive js validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editortemplates

I'm trying to add a `Class` to the `EditorFor` Helper inside an `EditorTemplate`.

The problem is that because I'm using **Unobtrusive Validation**, the input element already has classes assigned to it.

Here is my EditorTemplate

```
@Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of Nullable(Of Date))
@Html.TextBox("", If(Model.HasValue, String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"), String.Empty), New With {.class = "datepicker"})
```

And here is the output

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="08/08/1980" />
```

You can see here that the `datepicker` class has not been added, yet the "value" has been properly formatted.

Basically I can see that the `EditorTemplate` is working, but the `Class` is not being appended to the rest of the classes on the `<input>` element.

Do any of you know how to fix this?

Comment: Random thought: first time I see VB.NET being used in MVC, let alone Razor.

Comment: Well, it will works. The support is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to add a `<UIHint("Date")>` to my Buddy Class.

All is right again.

```
@ModelType Date?
@Html.TextBox("", If(Model.HasValue, String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model), String.Empty), New With {.class = "datepicker"})
```

Here's the reason for the UIHint.

> The default template name is based on the CLR type name, in this case DateTime. "Date" is a shortcut name in VB, not the real type name (much like "int" in C# is really a shortcut for CLR's "Int32").

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
@Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of Nullable(Of Date))
@Html.TextBox("", If(Model.HasValue, String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"), String.Empty), new {.class = "datepicker"})
```

Comment: The only difference I'm seeing is the `new` vs the `New With`.  Which is the difference between VB and C#